# Excel not showing the full page contents

Tags: pdf, microsoft-excel-2013, margins

In Microsoft Excel 2013 under Microsoft Windows 8, for a Letter 215.9 x 279.4 mm Page Size with zero margins (0 mm, 0 mm, 0 mm, 0 mm), and set at 100%, and cells set as 10 px Column Width x 10 px Row Height (2.7 x 2.7 mm), I can draw a rectangle which can reach at most 201 x 288 mm, which in both the Excel Print Preview Saved As PDF *and* in the Final PDF is shown covering the full page, showing no relevant bleeding at all.

I have lost 15 mm at left and gain 8 mm top in bleeding (!), far from the 2.7 mm error due to Column | Row sizes.

Why I have lost 15mm? Did Excel scaled everything?

Excel Options

[image]

[image]

Excel Page View

[image]

Excel Page Setup

[image]
[image]

Excel Print Preview

[image]

PDF Viewer

[image]

Comment: Does changing to print 1 x 1 pages persist with the same issue?

Comment: excel will have very little content can not be displayed in full.

Comment: @Ceasar 15mm is not so little content !!